# Deleting Entire contents of Sharepoint List via Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint-list

So I have a class I've made in Excel that manages connecting to a SharePoint List and either returning a recordset or executing SQL.

Here is that code:

```
Option Explicit

'***********************************************************************************
'SharepointListClass helps hold SQL code and gives convenient functions to call that SQL code.
'Requires Reference: Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library
'***********************************************************************************

Private zLines As New Collection
Private zConnection As ADODB.Connection

Public Sub Add(ByVal sqlLine As String)

'**************************************************************************************
'    DESCRIPTION:
'       This will add a line of SQL as a string to the collection
'
'    INPUT VARS:
'       sqlLine: The string of SQL code to add to the bottom of the collection
'**************************************************************************************

    Dim addSql As String: addSql = sqlLine
    'Makes sure that the right is always a space since this will not hold SQL code with new paragraphs.
    If VBA.Right(addSql, 1) <> " " Then
        addSql = addSql & " "
    End If

    zLines.Add addSql

End Sub

Public Sub Blank()

'**************************************************************************************
'    DESCRIPTION:
'       This will add a element to the collection that contains a vbnullstring. This
'       only helps when trying to view the code in a readable form (printsql)
'
'    INPUT VARS:
'       n/a
'**************************************************************************************

    zLines.Add vbNullString

End Sub

Public Sub Clear()

'**************************************************************************************
'    DESCRIPTION:
'       This will clear all code from the collection
'
'    INPUT VARS:
'       n/a
'**************************************************************************************

    Set zLines = New Collection

End Sub

Public Function Code() As String

'**************************************************************************************
'    DESCRIPTION:
'       This returns a string showing the full SQL code held within this Class instance.
'       NO PARAGRAPHS SHOWN
'
'    INPUT VARS:
'       n/a
'**************************************************************************************

    Dim str As String

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To zLines.Count
        str = str & zLines(i)
    Next

    'Remove double spaces, to reduce size of string
    Do Until InStr(str, "  ") = 0
        str = Replace(str, "  ", " ")
    Loop

    'Excel can only send a query to the SQL Server of 32,767 or less, this will throw an error on purpose so you know this is what cause the issue.
    If Len(str) > 32767 Then
        Dim xxx As Integer: xxx = 1000000 'errors on purpose
    End If

    Code = str

End Function

Public Sub PrintSql()

'**************************************************************************************
'    DESCRIPTION:
'       Prints SQL code in the Immediate Window, this will show each line as a new line
'       For debug purposes
'
'    INPUT VARS:
'       n/a
'**************************************************************************************

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To zLines.Count
        Debug.Print zLines(i)
    Next

End Sub

Public Sub OpenConnection(SharepointSite As String, ListName As String)

'**************************************************************************************
'   DESCRIPTION:
'       Opens a connection to the SQL server and database to have Code run off of it
'
'   INPUT VARS:
'       DataSource:   The address of the SQL Server
'       DatabaseName: The database name within the server
'**************************************************************************************

    If zConnection Is Nothing Then Set zConnection = New ADODB.Connection

    Debug.Print "Sharepoint reconnected"
    zConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                                   "WSS;" & _
                                   "IMEX=0;" & _
                                   "RetrieveIds=Yes;" & _
                                   "DATABASE=" & SharepointSite & ";" & _
                                   "LIST=" & ListName & ";"

    zConnection.Open

End Sub

Public Sub CheckConnection()

'**************************************************************************************
'   DESCRIPTION:
'       Checks if the connection object exists and creates it if not. Also checks if the
'       database is conenected, if not connects it.
'
'   INPUT VARS:
'       n/a
'**************************************************************************************

    If zConnection Is Nothing Then Set zConnection = New ADODB.Connection

    If zConnection.State <> adStateOpen Then
        OpenConnection SharepointSite:="https://<Sharepoint address>/", _
                       ListName:="lstQuoteWinLoss"
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub CloseConnection()

'**************************************************************************************
'   DESCRIPTION:
'       Closes the connection made by OpenConnection
'
'   INPUT VARS:
'       n/a
'**************************************************************************************

    zConnection.Close

End Sub

Public Sub SetConnection(conn As ADODB.Connection)

    Set zConnection = conn

End Sub

Public Function GetQueryRecordset() As ADODB.Recordset

'**************************************************************************************
'   DESCRIPTION:
'       This will create an ADODB.recordset from the SQL code and server and return it
'       as a recordset object.
'
'   INPUT VARS:
'       n/a
'**************************************************************************************

    On Error GoTo FUNC_ERR

    Dim t As Integer: t = 1

GET_RST:
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    CheckConnection
    Set rst.ActiveConnection = zConnection
    rst.Source = Me.Code
    rst.Open

    Set GetQueryRecordset = rst

FUNC_EXIT:
    Exit Function

FUNC_ERR:
    If Error = -2147217871 And t < 5 Then
        t = t + 1
        GoTo GET_RST
    Else
        MsgBox "Error Numuber: " & Err.Number & vbLf & Err.Description
        End
    End If

End Function

Public Sub Execute()

    zConnection.Execute Code

End Sub
```

And then I use it in my code like so

```
Dim spSQL As New SharepointListClass
With spSQL
    .OpenConnection SharepointSite:="https://<Sharepoint address>/", ListName:="lstQuoteWinLoss"
    .Add "DELETE FROM lstQuoteWinLoss"
    .Execute
End With
```

That all seems to work fine, but I want to be able to clear that SharePoint List and then populate it with new data. However, I'm running into issues in doing that.

If I use a normal SQL statement like `DELETE FROM tblQuoteWinLoss`, it does start to delete lines, however, it seems to do it one at a time that takes incredibly long. I can hit refresh on the SharePoint website and see the numbers decreasing. Plus, for some reason it seems to trip on it's own toes and throw this error every 25 to 30 seconds. If I just select debug and hit the play button, it does a bunch more and then throws the error again.

[image]

After doing some googling, I stumbled across another feature that is supposed to be quick for clearing tables `TRUNCATE TABLE lstQuoteWinLoss`. However, that doesn't seem to be supported by either SharePoint or the method I'm using to execute code through VBA.

[image]

So my question is, does anyone know a method I can use to clear the table quickly so that I can then add new items back into it? Thanks!

---EDIT---
After some testing, it would seem that it deletes exactly 100 lines before throwing the readonly error, which seems like something else is happening here. Any ideas?

Comment: If I were you, I'd proxy the SharePoint calls with something like an Azure Function (Graph API) or a LogicApp.

Comment: I'll have to look into how to do that to see if it'll work for me

Comment: @JasonBrady I'm getting the same error, used to work fine for a few months and now it's doing the exact same thing when I try to delete records, after 40s I get the same error.. Did you find a solution for that?

Comment: Having same issue. Has anyone found a solution for this?

Comment: I never found a solution, in the end I ran the delete call over and over. But it is highly impractical if you have any significant amount of rows. I had about a 1000 and it would take 5-10 mins. I've since then been able to move it into SQL and gotten away from this issue all together.